# Simple method to multiply two ints in Dafny with invariant

Tags: methods, dafny

This `Q3` method commutes n0 * m0 by adding m0 to res |n0| times. If n0 is negative, we invert both n0 and m0 as n0*m0 = -n0* -m0 holds.

The problem I have is that I don't exactly know what my invariant should look like because invariants need to be of type boolean. Can anybody tell me what the invariant boolean condition may look like? I thought about `Abs((n0)-n)*m == res`, but that doesn't work.

```
method Q3(n0 : int, m0 : int) returns (res : int)
  ensures n0*m0 == res
{

  var n, m : int;
  res := 0;
  if (n0 >= 0) 
     {n,m := n0, m0;} 
  else 
     {n,m := -n0, -m0;}

  while (0 < n) 
  invariant Abs((n0)-n)*m
  { 
    res := res + m; 
    n := n - 1; 
  }
}

function Abs(x: int): int
{
  if x < 0 then -x else x
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to design a loop invariant, it's helpful to first work backwards. What do you need to know after the loop terminates?

For this method, once the loop terminates, you will need to establish the postcondition `n0 * m0 == res`, so this is our starting point for a loop invariants.

Since `res` is changed by the loop, `n0 * m0 == res` is not itself an invariant. Instead, we have to think about how the loop "makes progress" towards this goal. This loop makes progress by adding `m` to `res`, doing so a total of `n` times, roughly speaking. When `n` is 0, the loop terminates.

A common pattern is useful here: the invariant should talk about what's been done "so far" and what's "left to do". In this case, what's been done so far is `res`, and what's left to do is the remaining `n` additions of `m`. Each iteration of the loop takes one piece of work left to do, and does it, maintaining the invariant.

In other words, a good invariant for this loop is `res + n * m == n0 * m0`.

Also, the [Dafny Tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Guide) has a section about loop invariants, which might be helpful.